# How to save Android logs on the go

Tags: android, logging, geolocation

I´m currently building an Android app, which tracks the user´s location. 
My aim is to test it on the go, so the device can´t be connected to my computer. 
Nevertheless I want to read my logs after returning back home.

What is the easiest way to save my logs on the device and show them in eclipse later? I just want to save my application´s logs.

Thank you,
Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the logs in some sort of formatted String, than start an email send intent to email them to yourself once complete.  or create some `List<DataType>` where `DataType` is an object holding some info about an event.  once complete, again email them in desired format

Comment: This is the simple solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The "logs" -- assuming that you mean LogCat -- are automatically "saved". LogCat is a 64KB ring buffer. You do not have to be plugged into Eclipse to log data. When you plug into Eclipse later, you will see the last 64KB of logs.

Comment: can I somehow see these tons of data in eclipse? My LogCat view stops adding logs after several lines

Comment: @Jonathan Roth: There is a vertical scrollbar on the right to allow you to scroll forwards and back through the data. You can also close Eclipse and launch the standalone DDMS utility (`tools/ddms` in your Android SDK) Beyond that, there may be something messed up with your device or Eclipse environment.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you please point to the source of this information?

Comment: @VinayWadhwa: Well, the sizes are variable nowadays. `adb logcat -g` will tell you the capacity of the LogCat buffer for your connected device or emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You could save your data into an sqllite database. Once you exit the app you'll dump the data to a file.

Comment: great idea, but isn´t this a little too complicated for such a simple task?

Comment: The question which you have to ask yourself is, how many data points do you want to save? Sure, you could certainly save them in a string(-builder) - but I like to use database - you have so many possebilities to use the data and it's not that hard to set up the database ( you just need to colums ( date and gps ) )

Comment: thats true, I´m currently having a look at how to create databases in android